# Creating a list of objects using the rows of a spreadsheet using openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, dictionary, openpyxl

I have a table in Excel as follows:

```
ID  Address         Type 
1   2 John Avenue   family 
2   3 John Avenue   single woman 
3   4 John Avenue   single man 
4   5 John Avenue   mixed couple 
5   6 John Avenue   youth 
6   7 John Avenue   family 
7   8 John Avenue   single woman
```

I want to read each line from the table (excluding the header) and turn each row into an instance of a "Person" class.

In order to do this, I am trying to read each row into a dictionary, with "id" as the key. I am using "openpyxl" to read from the Excel file. Once I am able to store the data from the Excel file into a dictionary, I plan to create instances of the "Person" class - although I am not sure that this is the best approach...

This is the code that I have so far:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook  

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id, address, type):
        self.id = id
        self.address = address
        self.type = type 

wb = load_workbook('sample.xlsx') 
sheet = wb.worksheets[0] 

row_count = sheet.max_row        
column_count = sheet.max_column     

header = []                 

for col in range (column_count):
    header.append(sheet.cell(0, col))

data = []
for row in range(1, row_count):
dict = {}
    for col in range(column_count):
        dict[header[row]]=sheet.cell(row,col)
    data.append(dict)

print (data)
```

I get the following error message:

*AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'upper'*

I think it might be an indexing error but I've tried to resolve it with no luck.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: It's always useful to include the full traceback because this will pinpoint the error. As it stands it's impossible to help you because we don't know where things are breaking down.

Comment: I'll remember to include the full traceback in future. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the following should do what you want.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, id=None, address=None, type=None):
        self.id = id # avoid using Python keywords where possible
        self.address = address
        self.type = type


wb = load_workbook('sample.xlsx')
sheetname = "Addresses"
ws = wb[sheetname]

# openpyxl >= 2.4
header = [cell.value for cell in ws[1]]
# openpyxl < 2.4
header = [cell.value for cell in ws.rows[0]]
people = []

for row in ws.rows[1:]:
    values = {}
    for key, cell in zip(header, row):
        values[key] = cell.value
    person = Person(**values)
    people.append(person)


# alternatively if the order is fixed

for row in ws.rows[1:]:
    args = [cell.value for cell in row]
    person = Person(*args)
    people.append(person)
```

Note that it's good practice not to overwrite Python keywords or use them as attributes to reduce confusion.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer, I really appreciate it. However, I got the following error message when I tried to run the code. Do you know how this can be rectified?: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/t/hi/hello.py", line 14, in <module>
    header = [cell.value for cell in ws[1]]
  File "/Users/t/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 336, in __getitem__
    if ":" in key:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You need to upgrade to openpyxl 2.4: `pip install -U --pre openpyxl`. Alternatively use `cell.value for cell in ws.rows[0]`

Comment: I upgraded to openpyxl 2.4 but now I get the following error message: Traceback: for row in ws.rows[1:]: TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2)` or `for row in list(ws.rows)[1:]` Depends a bit on the size of the worksheet as to whether you want to worry about the size of objects in memory.

Comment: That worked after I removed one of the asterisks: person = Person(*values) instead of person = Person(**values). Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working. You might want to lookup the `def func(*args, **kw)` style in the docs. https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-parameter

Comment: You have a spelling mistake: `peopele` instead of `people`

Comment: `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable`